# Pages Column Sorting Wordpress Version 3.0.3

Tags: pages

I am working on a wordpress site that is stuck on version 3.0.3 - Desperately trying to make the Title / Author / Category / Etc columns sortable.

At present all pages are listed in order of last update and working with over 800 pages it is an absolute nightmare. Sadly upgrading the version of WP is not an option otherwise this would be a piece of cake.

I have tried to google a solution but can only find custom post type sorting info.

Can anyone suggest a solution? Sorry for the lack of "research" but am stuck when it comes to old versions of wp

Comment: you don't want that we help you to update WordPress ? that will help you for the futur improvements that you will bring to the site

Comment: Oh tell me about it, I am currently redeveloping the site using current wordpresss but there is a LOT of 'red tape' in the company I work for. As infuriating as it is I am stuck with 3.0.3 hence my dilemma. Cannot even use ACF!

Any advice on how to manually set up sorting on this version?